# How can I send string parameter with file uploading?

Tags: android

In my android project I upload images with a category of the image. Is there any ways to send the category string with my uploading file?

This is my uploading code, how can I send the category string in this:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoInput(true); 
conn.setDoOutput(true); 
conn.setUseCaches(false); 
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
   + fileName + """ + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way it can be solved is by sending a JSON object string which has "imageContent" and "imageCategory" as attributes, encoding image content as base64 string on the Android client and decoding it back to normal on the backend.

```
Bitmap currentPhotoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
currentPhotoBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] currentPhotoBitmapAsByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(currentPhotoBitmapAsByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If you wanna go this way, you should change your headers to match text requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general question "How to include Information in a HTTP request".
One option would be to add it as an HTTP header.

In your example this would be accomplishable by adding:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("X-Image-Category", someCategory);
```

Whats not covered here is, that the Server also needs to read this Header and do something with the Category.